# Capturing and storing Referrer

Tags: php, insert, http-referer

I apologise upfront this is really simply but causing me much annoyance. I have only been working on PHP a week or so and really learning by need at the minute. Below is my current issue. I am trying to pick up the Google Referral Keyword. Managed that now cant understand why it wont insert the value into the dbase table.

```
// capture referral url
$referringPage = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
if ( stristr( $referringPage['host'], 'google.' ) )
{
  parse_str( $referringPage['query'], $queryVars );
  echo $queryVars['q']; // This is the search term used
}

// general form data insert
$sql="INSERT INTO refer_kws (kwid, keyword)
VALUES('','what value should I have here')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "";

mysql_close($con)

?>
```

I have tried several of the options and they just keep inputting Array as the value?? But when I use "? echo $_GET['q'] ?" on the page it works fine and displays the value?

I know this is simple. I really do but just cant get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put the array between '', that will make it a string. Because the string value of an array is "Array" it will store "Array" in the database. `VALUES('',$referringPage)`

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark my answer as the right one :)

Answer (score 0):

you should make a query separate for each type of website as Google will send the customer to you with keywords in 'q' `GET` variable, and modify the table to add referrer host:

```
 $referringPage = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
 if ( stristr( $referringPage['host'], 'google.' ) ){
   parse_str( $referringPage['query'], $queryVars );
   // echo $queryVars['q']; // This is the search term used  --- no need to print this
   $sql="INSERT INTO refer_kws (`kwid`, `host`, `keyword`) VALUES('',  $referringPage['host'], $queryVars['q'])";

 } else {
    $sql="INSERT INTO refer_kws (`kwid`, `host`, `keyword`) VALUES('', $referringPage['host'], '')"; // other type of referrers -  you can insert the full REFERRER here!
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check following code may help you, which value is to put.

```
var_dump($referringPage);
if ( stristr( $referringPage['host'], 'google.' ) )
{
  parse_str( $referringPage['query'], $queryVars );
  var_dump($queryVars);
  echo $queryVars['q']; // This is the search term used
}
```